# Formula for adding columns of a row till the last column in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I want to sum the columns of a row and display the sum in the last column. As shown in the example below sum of each row is displayed in column `TOTAL`

> ```
>             COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    TOTAL
>     ROW1     4       6       2        1      13
>     ROW2     2       2                2       6
> ```

In the future, more columns may be added. So I want a formula for column `TOTAL` that can find the sum of range `COL1` to `TOTAL`-1.

Answer (score -3):

You can do `sum(range)` you can pass it a range in R1C1 format. So you can build that string from the getcolumn of the total column and the startcolumn, alternatively you can use a named range.

You might also do something like find in the header row and search for total there to find the column index, but I don't remember how to do that.